# Spring data elasticSearch : Update entity using alias

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm currently fighting with the `spring-data-elasticsearch` API. I need it to work on an alias with several indexes pointing on it.
Each indexes have the same types stored, but are juste day to day storage (1rst index are monday's resulsts, second are tuesday's resulsts....).

Some of the `ElasticsearchRepository` methods don't work because of the alias. I currently managed to do a search (`findOne() equivalent`) but I am not able to update an entity.
I don't know how to achieve that, I looked to the documentation and samples.. but I'm stuck.

**My repository**

```
public interface EsUserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, String>
{
    @Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"term\" : {\"id_str\" : \"?0\"}}}}")
    User findByIdStr(String idStr);
}
```

**My Entity**

```
@Document(indexName = "osintlab", type = "users")
public class User
{
    // Elasticsearch internal id
    @Id
    private String id;

    // Just a test to get the real object index (_index field), in order to save it
    @Field(index = FieldIndex.analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
    private String indexName;

    // Real id, saved under the "id_str" field
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String id_str;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private List<String> tag_user;

}
```

**What I tested**

```
final IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQuery();
indexQuery.setId(user.getId());
indexQuery.setObject(user);

esTemplate.index(indexQuery);

userRepository.index(user));

userRepository.save(user))
```

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html) is pretty clear on the fact that `All CRUD APIs are single-index APIs. The index parameter accepts a single index name, or an alias which points to a single index.` So you need to use an index name in your update queries.

Comment: Yes, that's I understood. But I didn't manage to get the indexname in my model. I can add an indexName field but it already exists in the ```_index``` one.
For the moment I use an extra index field. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is `osintlab` an alias name? If yes, then you should use an index name instead.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-aliases.html#aliases-write-index , you can flag one index to be the one to use for write operations with `"is_write_index" : true`